# How to get all unread email from exchange server from controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, email

I want to read emails from the exchange server in my mvc4 code and then save it to SQL Server table. For this firstly, I am trying to connect to exchange server using exchange web services(EWS).

I added exchange service API from nuget in my Visual studio 2012 and Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.dll reference.

and added `using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;` namespace in my controller.

I am trying to follow this [link](http://www.thingswelearned.com/article/show/working-with-exchange-server-using-web-service-ews-exchange-server-asp-net).

I am not sure if I have started correctly. Please let me know if my approach is correct or any other way to achieve this and also how to proceed.

Comment: SO is not the right place to discuss 'approach'. You may still get answers for this question but in general, you will have try, face errors, put up what you tried with errors and then the good people of SO help you resolve it.

Comment: If you don't mind paying for a library, http://independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/index.html, is worth a look. It is not cheep but works well. It does have a free trial so you can see if it works for you. I've no affiliation with the company. I've just used the product in the past.